# Status: "MariaDB server is down" mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mariadb

I need help as my mysql server is stuck.

Operating system: `CentOS 8`

What have I tried so far based on information received from `/var/log/mysql`:

(1) Reinstalling the server: `sudo apt reinstall mariadb-server`. No positive change

(2) Disabling the `gssapi module`: I commented out `plugin-load-add=auth_gssapi.so` in my `/etc/my.cnf`

(3) Extending the limit of max files handling: `sudo systemctl edit mariadb.service` then added the line:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=102400
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

(4) Set my innodb in recovery mode: `vi /etc/my.cnf` then `innodb_force_recovery=1`

So far I am stuck and I am strongly pressed to find a solution

`Status: "MariaDB server is down"`

```
Aug 24 19:30:51 steve systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
Aug 24 19:30:51 steve mysql-check-socket[3034]: Socket file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.
Aug 24 19:30:51 steve mysql-check-socket[3034]: No process is using /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, which means it is a garbage, so it will be removed>
Aug 24 19:30:52 steve mysql-prepare-db-dir[3062]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.
Aug 24 19:30:52 steve mysql-prepare-db-dir[3062]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mysql-prepare-db->
Aug 24 19:30:52 steve mysqld[3100]: 2022-08-24 19:30:52 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.17-MariaDB) starting as process 3100 ...
Aug 24 19:30:53 steve systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 24 19:30:53 steve systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is in the '/var/log/mysql' pertinent to the most recent start attempt? Edit the question with these details formatted for readability.